# Look up an account then average associated values excluding zeros

Tags: average, lookup, sumifs

On one sheet, I have account code and in the cell next to it, I need to look up the account code on the next sheet to average the cost excluding those cells that are zero in col. b from the average calculation.

The answer for London should be: £496.33 but having tried various sumifs / countifs I cannot get it to work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `SUM` and `COUNTIF` is the way to go. Show what you have tried, so we can see where the error is ...

Comment: =SUMIFS('ESL Info'!$R:$R,'ESL Info'!H:H,$B$28)/COUNTIF('ESL Info'!$H:$H,$B$28) This is one attempt at trying but the formula is not excluding the rows that are zero.

Comment: Without knowing wath the content of `B28` is, it's quite hard to say anything. But your `COUNTIF` will count all values from the given range that are equal to `B28` ...

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example with (anonymized!) input data and the expected result ...

Comment: I have also tried that but that does not work either. The first part of the formula needs to look up the account number in col B then go to the next sheet to find that account number and add up col B with values that are not zero and then average the result excluding the rows where in col B the total is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) which  -- similar to the `SUMIFS` you are already using -- allows to define multiple critera and ranges.
So, if the column `R` contains the values, you want to build the average upon, and the column `H` in the respective row must equal `$B$28` to be included in the sum, the respective `COUNTIFS` looks as follows

```
=SUMIFS('ESL Info'!$R:$R,'ESL Info'!H:H,$B$28)/COUNTIFS('ESL Info'!$H:$H,$B$28, 'ESL Info'!$R:$R, "<>0")
```

ie additionally to the value in the `H`-column to equal `B28` it also requires the value `R`-column (ie the actual number you are summing up) to be different from `0`

You could also add the same criteria `'ESL Info'!$R:$R, "<>0"` to your `SUMIFS`, but that isn't necessary, because a `0` doesn't provide anything to you sum, thus it doesn't matter if it's included in the sum or not ...

And depending on the Excel version you are using, you may even have the [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) function available, which does exactly what you want

```
=AVERAGEIFS('ESL Info'!$R:$R,'ESL Info'!$H:$H;$B$28,'ESL Info'!$R:$R,"<>0")
```

Comment: That has returned "#Value"

Comment: Col H does contain the account, ie: "london" and column R are the values. Col B is the account "London" to be identified from Col H.

Comment: Then something is off in your sheet. The countifs works fine with me, given the ranges' size is equal

Comment: You are correct! I had put row numbers in one part of the formula but not the other part. Works fine now - Thank you!

Comment: If that answer works for you, feel free to accept it (click on the checkmark)